# Difficulties with .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a project (a shoutbox) that requires a form to be submitted without reloading the page.Should be easy, right? Well, I'm using jQuery, and I'm running in to a problem. When I only have one `input` box, everything works fine. But if I have two, it breaks.

Form -

```
<form id="freeshout-form" method="post">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="name" />
    <input id="entry" type="text" name="entry" value="entry" />
</form>
```

jQuery -

```
$("#freeshout-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($("#name").val() + ' - ' + $("#entry").val());
    });
```

However, if I remove one of the input boxes the alert box will show the value of that input and "undefined" for the value of [what would have been] the other input value. But if I put the input value I took out back in, the alert box doesn't show up at all.

Any ideas?

Update: Works on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/4BNbJ/), but not [on my site](http://andrew.x10.mx/freeshout/). Same code, though, and I removed everything that could possibly interfere with it.

Comment: works fine: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4BNbJ/

Comment: @Andrew: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to work? See -- http://jsfiddle.net/gPSje/

Comment: That's...weird. I have no other JS on the page besides the link to the jQuery source, and it doesn't work. =/

Comment: @Andrew: Did you forget to use `$(document).ready(function() {});`?

Comment: @stealthy: That's probably not it. If it was a DOM ready issue, the `submit` handler wouldn't fire at all.

Comment: @stealhyninka: No, I used it. I just put it online - http://andrew.x10.mx/freeshout/. That doesn't work for me either, and it's the same code -- although jsfiddle works. Does the above work for you all? I cleared the browsers cache, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @jAndy & @stealthyninja got an `<input type="submit">` that's why it works for them and not for you maybe.

Comment: I thought `.submit()` acted as a submit button, and meant I didn't have to use one and could just use the return key. >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine when I add a submit button. You can add an invisible one. Or you could have the form listen for the "Enter" key.

---

Perhaps a caching issue. Clear your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: @Andrew: I just updated. Your code works fine when I add a submit button. Start with that.

Comment: Ohh. I wanted the form to submit when the user hit the return key, and I didn't realize I still needed the submit button in the code. Do you think I'll run in to any problems if I add the submit button and hide it? I just tested it and it works (hitting the return key while hidden), but I just want to see if it's "okay" to do that. Meh. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Andrew: I tried it with `display:none` in Chrome, and it seemed to give troubles. I may have messed something else up though. I'd do some testing. You could probably search SO for "submit form on enter key" or something.